# Toggle multiple classes on host element against single expression

Tags: angular, typescript

Since you can't use `ngClass` in a host binding like so:

```
host: { '[ngClass]': "{ 'spinner spinner-large': !loaded }" }
```

Is there any other means of toggling multiple classes against a single expression? (In lieu of the following)

```
host: { '[class.spinner]': '!loaded',
        '[class.spinner-large]': '!loaded' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
host: { '[class]': "!loaded ? 'spinner spinner-large' : ''" }
```